# How to calculate a missing middle digit of a multiplication between 2 big numbers using modular arithmetic?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

What elementary number theory methods can I use for solving this type of questions?

One of these kind of problems is to find $x$ where $985242x6565 = 172195\cdot 572167$ without multiplying the numbers again.

I tried doing, let's call $985242x6565$ $N$, $N\text{mod}10^5$ to somehow get to the $5th$ digit but this is doesn't get me anywhere and in hindsight it doesn't make any sense. How should I proceed?

Comment: Try thinking modulo $11$.  If that doesn't work, then additionally try looking at another modulo as well on top of this.  Do you know the easy way to find a number's value modulo $11$?

Comment: Modulo 9 is also often useful.

Comment: @Jaap modulo $9$ sometimes has a hard time distinguishing between the missing digit being a $9$ versus a $0$ (*as is the case here*).  As $11>10$ we can skip that frustration by using $11$ instead which is a similarly low calculation required aproach.

Comment: @JMoravitz I'd still take those odds and would generally try 9 first, just because the mental arithmetic is slightly easier and hence less error-prone. If it gives an ambiguous result or if I was feeling unsure, only then would I go for 11 as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The alternating sum and difference of digits from right to left of a number is equivalent modulo 11 to the original number.

$172195\mapsto 5-9+1-2+7-1=1$

$572167\mapsto 7-6+1-2+7-5=2$

So the first number is equivalent to $1$ modulo $11$ and the second is equivalent to $2$ modulo $11$.  Their product should then be $1\cdot 2=2$ modulo $11$.

We have $5-6+5-6+x-2+4-2+5-8+9=x+4$ and we want this to be $2$ more than a multiple of $11$ with $x$ being a digit.  This happens precisely when $x=9$.

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't come across a problem laid out like this, quick and easy, much appreaciated!

Comment: Please strive not to add more dupe answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. site policy [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).

Answer (score 1):

The remainder of the division by 11 is equal to the alternating sum of the digits of the number. Because
$1 \equiv 1$ (mod 11)
$10 \equiv -1$ (mod 11)
$100 \equiv 1$ (mod 11)
$1000 \equiv -1$ (mod 11)
$10000 \equiv 1$ (mod 11)
and so on...

Thus,
$172195 \equiv (-1+7-2+1-9+5) \equiv 1$ (mod 11)
$572167 \equiv (-5+7-2+1-6+7) \equiv 2$ (mod 11)
$172195⋅572167 \equiv 1\cdot2 \equiv 2$ (mod 11)

$985242x6565 \equiv (9-8+5-2+4-2+x-6+5-6+5) \equiv 4+x$ (mod 11)
and $x\equiv9$ (mod 11).

Answer: $x=9$